# Conditionally using one column or another in a Where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return rows from a MySQL table against one of two columns conditionally depending on which is NULL and which is not.

In the following example if the value of subNetOfID is not NULL and I query for a subNetOfID value of 1, then return rows 3, 4, 5, 6.

If however I ask for a subNetOfID of 2 then I want the rows related to it. In this case 1,2,5,6 because rows 1,2 are parent rows to 3,4 based on NetID, and the subNetOfID values being the same.

Simple Table with four columns:

```
Fname   Lname  NetID  subNetOfID
Bob     Smith   1      NULL
Jon     Jones   1      NULL
Cam     Tomes   2      1
Bill    Holt    2      1
Tom     Hanks   3      1
Phil    Howard  3      1
```

```
If my query is subNetOfID=
1,  Return rows 3 to 6  (the subNetOfIDvalue is 1)     --> This part is easy.
2,  Return rows 1,2,5,6 (NetID is 1 or subNetOfIDis 1) --> 
3,  Return rows 1,2,3,4 (NetID is 1 or subNetOfIDis 1) -->
```

I've tried a variety of queries these being my latest. But getting it to work for all three possibilities is giving me fits. What do I need to do to make it work for all three cases?

```
 SELECT Fname, Lname, NetID, subNetOfID  FROM `NetLog` 
  HAVING ((NetID != 0 AND subNetOfID = 2) OR 
   (subNetOfID IS NOT NULL AND subNetOfID != '') AND (NetID = 2))


 SELECT *, subNetOfID as NID FROM NetLog
  HAVING((subNetOfID = 2)
     OR (subNetOfID != 2 
    AND (subNetOfID = NID AND NetID != 2 )))
```

Comment: can we chat or phone
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql-and-relational-databases

Comment: Why aren't you returning the first two rows when the value is 1?

Comment: You need to clarify your concept of parentage, among other things.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  If the value of subNetOfID is NULL then I don't need those rows.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the question

Comment: @Uueerdo If you think of the this very simple table NetID 2 and 3 have a pointer called subNetOfID that has a value of 1, which is the for all practical purposes the "parent" of them. But I was just using that term to better clarify what I was asking for. Sorry if it confused instead.

Comment: @Bernd Buffen I admit it, I'm not very good at asking these questions. Sorry.

Comment: are you from germany ?

Comment: i dont understand which is your input parameter for the query. with your logic every time all rows are returned

Comment: I'm still testing but I think this is it.   SELECT * FROM NetLog 
 WHERE ((subNetOfID = 1 
    OR (select subNetOfId from NetLog 
         WHERE NetID = 1 limit 1))
   AND (NetID != 0 AND NetID !=1))